# Why string get from buffer does not equal to JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am working on a project in which I am using node js and python together. My node js code makes a child process of python code. And I am sending some data from node js to python and also receiving some data back from python to node.

I call my python file like this.

```
const py = spawn('python', ['file.py', 'some_data']);
```

and for sending data back from python to node I am using print in python like this.

```
print("mydata")
```

and for receiving in nodejs I am using this code.

```
py.stdout.on('data', async (data) => {
                //This data is python string as we can see above
                var data_from_python = data.toString();
            });
```

now the problem I am facing is string which come from python does not equal to node js string I have tried this.

```
data_from_python === "mydata" // false
```

and also this

```
data_from_python == "mydata" // false
```

both returns false.

But when I **console** the **type** of both using **typeof** operator it says **string** for both.

I want to know what is reason behind and what is the solution if we want to compare them or is there a better way to get data back from python to node. I know this **"mydata"**  string is coming from buffer, python is putting it into the buffer and node is reading it from the buffer, and I think they both are different because one is python string and other is nodejs string, maybe it is because of under the hood both deal or make strings differently.

But what is the exact story behind if anyone one know please share your knowledge.

Comment: Try console logging `data_from_python` and see what it is.

Comment: I have already tried it console exact same mydata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because print in python adds a new line after the data, So instead of getting `mydata` you will receive `mydata\r\n`. So you should check for the same in your condition, see below:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const py = spawn('python', ['py.py', 'some_data']);

py.stdout.on('data', async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var data_from_python = data.toString();
    console.log(data_from_python == "mydata\r\n"); // outputs true
});
```

Comment: Yes I have check it works. Thanks a lot. it worked.